# Get data-testid and attributes from html using Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Web-dev newbie here. so please be nice.

I find this tag really weird for me to parse.

Consider the following HTML doc:

```
import urllib3
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.carrefourkuwait.com/mafkwt/en/Frozen-Food/c/FKWT6000000?currentPage=1&filter=&nextPageOffset=0&pageSize=60&sortBy=relevance'

req = urllib3.PoolManager()
res = req.request('GET', url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.data, 'html.parser')
soup
```

I am trying to get the product name and price. But using `soup.findAll('div', {'data-testid': 'product_name'})` doesn't work.

The issue here is that product name and price are attributes of a link in the `<a\>` tag. Even with  `soup.findAll('a')` I get nothing: `[]`

[image]
Can you please help with this?

I also unable to scroll over the pages. I wrote this code but it doesn't work (keep giving me duplicate from page =1)

```
tag = 'Bakery/c/FKWT1610000' 

scrap_all = pd.DataFrame()

for x in tqdm(range(1,10)):
    scrap_page = pd.DataFrame()
    r = requests.get(parent_url+tag+'?currentPage='+str(x)+'&filter=&nextPageOffset=0&pageSize=200&sortBy=relevance',
                     headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'})
    
    data = json.loads(re.search(r'(\{"prop.*\})', r.text).group(1))
    data = data['props']['initialState']['search']['products']
    scrap_page['item_desc'] = [i['name'] for i in data]
    scrap_page['item_price'] = [i['originalPrice'] for i in data]

    scrap_carrefour = pd.concat([scrap_carrefour,scrap_page])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Data is dynamically pulled from a script tag. As javascript doesn't run with requests this info remains within the script tag and is not present where you are looking.

You can regex out the string holding the relevant info, parse with json and create a dict as follows:

```
import requests, re, json

r = requests.get('https://www.carrefourkuwait.com/mafkwt/en/Frozen-Food/c/FKWT6000000?currentPage=1&filter=&nextPageOffset=0&pageSize=60&sortBy=relevance',
                 headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'})
data = json.loads(re.search(r'(\{"prop.*\})', r.text).group(1))
info = {i['name']:str(i['originalPrice'])+ ' '+ i['currency'] for i in data['props']['initialState']['search']['products']}
```

Comment: wow, I wish I could upvote twice! thank you

Comment: hi there - many thanks dear QHarr for this great asset in Python-Learning! Awesome!

Comment: @QHarr, one more question please? It looks like I can only scrap the first page. can you please provide more details how to do it. This very different from usual webscrap I used to do. I added a code snippet to my question for more details.

Comment: I would suggest opening a new question. It is likely the page does a POST XHR request for the additional pages and you may need to recreate those.

Comment: perfect! I just posted a separate question for that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68150767/webscrap-cant-to-move-to-the-next-page-using-page-tags