# Webscraping: can't to move to the next page using page tags

Tags: javascript, python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

This is a follow-up to [my last question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67959195/7362261).

Now I can extract the data I needed, I want to move to the next page and it seems that using page tags is not working. Here is the code I used:

```
import pandas as pd
import urllib3
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, re, json
from tqdm import tqdm
scrap_carrefour = pd.DataFrame() #columns =['Item_name','Item_price']


parent_url = 'https://www.carrefourkuwait.com/mafkwt/en/'
tags = [
    'Frozen-Food/c/FKWT6000000', 
    'Baby-Products/c/FKWT1000000', 
    'Beverages/c/FKWT1500000', 
    'Bakery/c/FKWT1610000'
      ]

max_page = 100 # page counter
page_size = 700 # number of product shown on the page

for tag in tags: 
    for x in tqdm(range(1,max_page)):
        scrap_page = pd.DataFrame()
        r = requests.get(parent_url+tag+'?currentPage='+str(x)
                         +'&filter=&nextPageOffset=0&pageSize=700'
                         ,
                         headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'})

        data = json.loads(re.search(r'(\{"prop.*\})', r.text).group(1))
        data = data['props']['initialState']['search']['products']
        scrap_page['item_desc'] = [i['name'] for i in data]
        scrap_page['item_price'] = [i['originalPrice'] for i in data]

        scrap_carrefour = pd.concat([scrap_carrefour,scrap_page]).drop_duplicates()
```

What happens is that it keeps web scraping the same page and even with a different page number.

Also, I would like the code to scrape all the products that's why I have an issue with page size as well.

I would appreciate some help on this!

Comment: Looks like this word ***scrap*** has spread like a pandemic.

Comment: Can you help me solve my issue, please? I am new to web scraping and I would appreciate it a lot

Comment: There is an API call for more results `https://www.carrefourkuwait.com/api/v5/zones/ZONE-1-kwt-051/search/categories/FKWT6000000?filter=&sortBy=relevance&currentPage=1&pageSize=700&areaCode=Zahra%20-%20Hawally&lang=en&expressPos=051&displayCurr=KWD&foodPos=&nonFoodPos=`

Comment: I suggest you start with a smaller page size so you can investigate how the number of times you press load more affects the API request. Find the pattern then replicate.

Comment: To get the content from that api suggested by @QHarr, make sure to add this ***'storeid': 'mafkwt', 'appid': 'Reactweb'*** within headers, otherwise it will fail to fetch the required response.

Comment: I got a `<Response [500]>` error! can you provide a reproducible snippet of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it.

```
import requests
from pprint import pprint
 
url = 'https://www.carrefourkuwait.com/api/v5/zones/ZONE-1-kwt-051/search/categories/{}'
 
categories = [
    'Frozen-Food/c/FKWT6000000', 
    'Baby-Products/c/FKWT1000000', 
    'Beverages/c/FKWT1500000', 
    'Bakery/c/FKWT1610000'
]

headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36',
    'storeid': 'mafkwt', 
    'appid': 'Reactweb'
}
 
params = {
    'filter': '',
    'sortBy': 'relevance',
    'currentPage': 0,
    'pageSize': '700',
    'areaCode': 'Zahra - Hawally',
    'lang': 'en',
    'expressPos': '051',
    'displayCurr': 'KWD',
    'foodPos': 'ZONE-1-kwt-051',
    'nonFoodPos': 'ZONE-1-kwt-051'
}

for cat in categories:
    cat_num = cat.split("/")[-1]
    api_link = url.format(cat_num)
    params['currentPage'] = 0

    while True:
        r = requests.get(api_link,params=params,headers=headers)
        if not r.json()['products']:break
        for item in r.json()['products']:
            print(item['name'])

        params['currentPage']+=1
```

Comment: Hey SIM, it worked so well. I really appreciate that. If you can, would you please tell me where I can learn such depth of details about web scraping?

Comment: I really don't know any specific source. However, you can check out different answers provided by `Andrej Kesely`, `QHarr`, `Baduker` and few others. They all work on that very angle you are interested in. Thanks.